# SCCM 2012 Application Deployment Keeps Failing

Tags: sccm-2012

I am trying to deploy the SCCM 2012 R2 Management Console to my virtual test systems and the damn thing keeps failing and I cannot put my finger on it. I need some help here. I put the same question on the TechNet Forums, but no one was able to help me, including the SCCM MVPs. Everything looks to be in order and my deployment seems to be configured correctly. The files download successfully to the ccmcache, but when I try to run them from the Software Center I receive the following error:

**0x80070654**

CMTrace states that this error is:

**This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.**

The AppEnforce.log shows the following error:

**Unmatched exit code (2147944020) is considered an execution failure.**

I can run the install from the package share, but when they get downloaded to the ccmcache I cannot run them at all. Something is corrupting the files from the Content Library to to the ccmcache on the cients, but I cannot figure it out.

Here is the original TechNet Forum question I posted:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb3b0bfc-0c60-40ea-95f0-25c261b610e1/getting-error-0x80070654-when-trying-to-install-sccm-2012-r2-console-from-software-center?forum=configmanagerapps

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

OKAY I figured out what the problem was. I originally had a package source share, but the deployment was still failing so I did away with that and used the admin share instead and it was still failing. Then I took a look at the Content Library share permissions and decided to just mirror that for a new package source share permissions and NTFS permissions.

**My Original Package Source Permissions**

- Local Admins Group: Full Control
- SCCM Admins AD Group: Full Control
- Domain Computers AD Group: Full Control

***Note:** I realized that assigning the Domain Computers account full control on the package source was not a best practice, but this was just a troubleshooting step and not something that was going to remain permanent. Also, because the package source is located on a separate drive (the Content Library is also located on another separate drive) on my Site Server and the fact that the SCCM Admins AD group was added to the Local Admins group a while back, I removed that group from being explicitly assigned since that was just another troubleshooting step and it did not solve anything.

**New Package Source Share Permissions**

- System Account: Full Control
- Local Admins Group: Full Control
- Local Users Group: Full Control

**New Package Source NTFS Permissions**

- System Account:Full Control
- Local Admins Group: Full Control
- Local Users Group: Read & execute

Then I forced inheritance from my package source to all child objects. After that, I changed the data source location for my deployments in the SCCM 2012 R2 console and then I updated all the content to the DP. After that, I used Right Click Tools to force a Machine Policy Retrieval & Evaluation Cycle on my Device Collection. Then, I went to my virtual test systems and ran the SCCM 2012 R2 Management Console deployment from Software Center and it installed just fine.

My original permissions did not have the System account assigned, so perhaps this is what the culprit was? I figured if the files were successfully downloading to the ccmcache, but were not able to install successfully then it must be something local on the system preventing it and that my permissions were fine. Obviously not the case. Anyway, it's fixed now and I can move on

Thanks everyone for trying to help me out with this issue.

I really appreciate your assistance.

Have a good one and I am quite sure I will be hitting you all up again some time soon.

Regards